# ERB to Haml rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Rails and haml expert, how to convert the following codes from ERB to HAML

```
<select name = "state">
<% CS.states(:us).each |key, value|%>
<option value = "<%= key %>"><%= value %></option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

FYI I am trying to make use of CityState gem to add Country state city choice to my rails app

Comment: did my solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this

```
   %select{:name => "state"}
      - CS.states(:us).each do |key, value|
      %option{:value => key}= value
```

You could also follow this [tutorial](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/70-convert-all-erb-templates-to-haml-across-project) to help you

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to use it together with simple_form. Tyring but still failing

Comment: Um actually no I'm not really familiar  simple_form

Comment: there is a "do" missing after (:us).each do |key, value|. Other than that, all good

Answer (score 0):

just paste your ERB code on HTML section here to convert it to HAML -> [htmltohaml conversion tool](http://htmltohaml.com/)